# Side effects of using a motor with a greater current on a battery with a lower rated current

Tags: lithium-ion, brushless-dc-motor, bms

I'm looking to power a 33A brushless DC 2000w 48v motor.

Ok so I have a lithium ion battery, and it's manufacturer states this:

Specs:

- 48v
- 1000w
- 13s3p
- 28Ah
- Rated discharge current: greater than or equal to 10A
- Maximum instantaneous current: 40A
- Maximum operating current: 13A

Now if the max operating current is 13A, then why would it say it comes with a 25A BMS?

Either way, my question is: with these specs, will my motor fry the battery? If not how long could it run on a charge?

Here is the manufacturer's description:

> 48V 28Ah 1000watt 13S3P 18650 Battery Pack MH1 54.6v E-bike Electric bicycle battery Scooter with 25A discharge BMS with charger

```
high capacity 48v 28Ah 1000w 13S3P Lithium ion Battery Pack For 54.6v E-bike Electric bicycle Scooter with discharge BMS
Product Parameters
Battery brand:okoman
Battery Type: 18650
Single cell voltage: 3.7V
Combination: 13 Series 3 and
Nominal voltage: 48V Input voltage: 48V Output voltage: 48V
After the combined capacity: 28000mAh (28Ah)
Battery Dimensions: 238 * 66 *60mm (There may be a 10 mm error) 3 * 13
Outside packaging: Blue PVC
Inside with protective circuit: overcharge, over discharge, over current, short circuit protection!
For other needs can contact the owner, thank you new and old customers.

The battery charging requirements: please in the shop to buy another charger!
1: the need for a dedicated lithium battery charger;
2: Charging voltage: 48V
3: Charge current: greater than or equal to 5A

The battery discharge requirements:

1: Output 18 lines, length 200mm, red and black each one
2: Enter the outlet line leads to a 2.1 length 200mm
3: Rated discharge current: greater than or equal to10A
4: maximum instantaneous current: 40A
5: Maximum operating current: 13A
```

Comment: why are you referring to an unknown BMS?

Comment: I don't know what BMS it comes with, it is pre installed

Comment: 1000W and 48V,13A cannot both be true. So we know the battery *specs* are garbage ... is the battery any better?  Now, running the motor at full power ... wait, what's the motor power? 48V * 33A is a lot less than 2000W. Make sure you run the motor at less than 13A (624W) and you'll be OK. If the motor controller can't do this current limit, find something which can. (13A or 15A breaker?)

Comment: If I don't limit the current, and the motor runs at full power, what will happen to the battery?

Comment: _"33A brushless DC 2000w 48v"_ - Is it this one? [Electric Brushless DC Motor Complete Kit, 48V 2000W 4300RPM High Speed Motor, With 33A 15 Mosfet Controller](https://www.amazon.com/Electric-Brushless-Complete-Controller-Motorcycle/dp/B07G2LZHD8)

Comment: _"if the max operating current is 13A, then why would it say it comes with a 25A BMS?"_ - translation error? Perhaps 'operating current' means charge current. Can you supply a link to the battery?

Comment: If the BMS includes an overcurrent protection, it will cut the battery output if the programmed threshold is exceeded. Battery will be save but your application will not work.

Comment: @Bruce_Abbott Yes it is

Comment: Link to battery: https://m.aliexpress.com/item/4000502457840.html?src=google&_randl_currency=USD&_randl_shipto=US&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=494-037-6276&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&albcp=9317063908&albag=94962804715&trgt=296730740870&crea=en4000502457840&netw=u&device=m&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq7XuvPKN6AIVUtbACh1NNQCKEAQYASABEgIG4fD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds